# Read access violation when using a pointer as a loop condition

Tags: c, pointers

I'm attempting to use pointers as conditions for a do...while loop that takes user input in C - but I keep getting a read access violation no matter what I try. I've tried to look everywhere I can for answers but I'm not really understanding well as I am very new to pointers. What am I doing wrong here?

```
//Sub prototype
void GetEmployeeInfo(int* pintEmployeeType);


//Actual sub code
void GetEmployeeInfo(int* pintEmployeeType)
{   
    //Getting employee type (if the entry is 1 they are a standard employee, while 2 is a manager)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter employee type ('1' for employee or '2' for manager).\n");
        scanf("%d", &pintEmployeeType);
    } 
    while (*pintEmployeeType != 1 && *pintEmployeeType != 2); //This is where I'm getting an exception
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &pintEmployeeType);` -> `scanf("%d", pintEmployeeType);`

Comment: Also, you need to be very aware that `scanf` will not consume the input if it doesn't match the format specifier. That is, if the user enters a non-number your `while` loop is likely to become an infinete loop because it will continuously try to read the invalid input. So in addition to checking the integer value you should first check the return value of `scanf`. If it does not return 1 you need to use something else, like `fgets`, to consume the input before proceeding to the next `scanf`.

Comment: cannot be determined with the code you've shown, but `pintEmployeeType` must point to valid memory before that memory can be accessed. Show the code leading up to and calling `GetEmployeeInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for you since you didn't provide one, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Sub prototype
void GetEmployeeInfo(int* pintEmployeeType);

int main(void)
{
    int empType;
    GetEmployeeInfo(&empType);

    printf("successfully returned, empType = %d\n", empType);
    return 0;
}

//Actual sub code
void GetEmployeeInfo(int* pintEmployeeType)
{   
    //Getting employee type (if the entry is 1 they are a standard employee, while 2 is a manager)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter employee type ('1' for employee or '2' for manager).\n");
        scanf("%d", pintEmployeeType);
    } 
    while (*pintEmployeeType != 1 && *pintEmployeeType != 2);
}
```

The program starts in `main` and reserves space for `empType` in automatic storage (probably 4 bytes and on a stack. None of these are mandated by the C standard, but assuming that to be the case for your C implementation moving forward).  After declaring `int empType;`, your stack frame for `main` now contains:

```
__ main __________________________
| Variable | Address | Value     |
|  empType |  0x1234 |  ???      |
----------------------------------
```

I've made the address up, but it has some address on your stack.  It has no value yet because nothing has been assigned to it.  Now when you call `GetEmployeeInfo` passing the *address* of `empType`, this is what (an abbreviated look at) your stack looks like^:

```
__ GetEmployeeInfo ___________________
| Variable         | Address | Value  |
| pintEmployeeType | 0x4567  | 0x1234 |---|
--------------------------------------|   |
| __ main ____________________________|   |
| empType          | 0x1234  |  ???   |<---
|_____________________________________|
```

It now has two *frames*, one for `GetEmployeeInfo` and one for `main`.  Again, I've made up the address for `pintEmployeeType`, but what I'm trying to illustrate with the arrow is that `pintEmployeeType` *points* to `empType`.  A pointer is nothing more than a variable whose value is an address to something else; in this case `pintEmployeeType` is an `int` pointer (or an `int*`), and its value is an address to `empType`, an `int`.

Your `scanf` line is wrong, because the `"%d"` format specifier expects an `int*` as a parameter.  `&` in this context means "the address of".  `pintEmployeeType` is already an `int*`, so taking the address of that is an `int**`.  This is something your compiler should warn you about; turn up its warning level if it isn't.  After fixing that line, we have

```
scanf("%d", pintEmployeeType);
```

Let's say you enter 4.  Now this is what our stack looks like^:

```
__ GetEmployeeInfo ___________________
| Variable         | Address | Value  |
| pintEmployeeType | 0x4567  | 0x1234 |---|
--------------------------------------|   |
| __ main ____________________________|   |
| empType          | 0x1234  |  4     |<---
|_____________________________________|
```

`pintEmployeeType` points back to `empType` in `main`; that hasn't changed.  What has changed is the value of `empType`.  When we hit the `while` loop

```
while (*pintEmployeeType != 1 && *pintEmployeeType != 2);
```

The `*` in this context means "dereference the pointer".  That is, "give me the value that the pointer is pointing to".  In this case, that's 4.  4 != 1 and 4 != 2, so it will loop back again and re-prompt.  Assuming you behave and always enter input that corresponds to the `"%d"` format specifier, this loop will continue until you enter 1 or 2, and break the loop.  Each time you enter a value, it's the value of `empType` that changes since this is what `pintEmployeeType` is pointing at.

As mentioned in the comments, you should at least check the return value of `scanf` to see if input matched your format specifier.  A more robust way of gathering user input is to use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read input in as a string and do your own parsing from there.

[code demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/hM895qxj5)

^ understand there's more on your stack than just these two variables (such as return pointers), omitting everything extra for clarity.

Comment: "You added a & in scanf when you shouldn't have" would have sufficed as answer... Or close vote as simple typo or duplicate.

Comment: Your answer is a nice effort, but would be more appropriate for a _"what is a pointer / how pointers works / etc."_ type question. In this case, as it's more a typo / basic debugging question, simply points the problem as Lundin states should suffice, optionally with a link on an _"how pointers works"_ .

Comment: @Lundin _I've tried to look everywhere I can for answers but I'm not really understanding well as I am very new to pointers._ was the crux of the matter. Not a simple typo for OP. Certainly a duplicate, but was in a mood to provide a detailed explanation of OP's specific problem.

Comment: Well, if writing/linking the whole pointer chapter of a book is the correct answer, then the question is per default far too broad for this Q&A site.

Comment: @Lundin ok maybe it is. Still not closed for "too broad" or "typo". Suspect it was a waste of time and OP is gone. Oh well, hardly think I've committed a cardinal sin here by trying to teach somebody. Besides, some of the most useful questions I've found on SO are closed/duped.

Comment: @Zilog80 same justification.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers - you were all a big help and I feel a little more confident in my use of pointers in this case!

Answer (score -2):

```
void GetEmployeeInfo(int* pintEmployeeType)
{   
    //Getting employee type (if the entry is 1 they are a standard employee, while 2 is a manager)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter employee type ('1' for employee or '2' for manager).\n");           
        scanf("%d[1|2] \n",pintEmployeeType);
        printf("you entered %d\n",*pintEmployeeType);

    } 
    while (*pintEmployeeType != 1 && *pintEmployeeType != 2); //This is where I'm getting an exception

}

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    GetEmployeeInfo(&x);
    return 0;
}
```